# Role of nontrivial component groups in Springer Correspondence?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, ag.algebraic-geometry

### Set-up for classical Springer Correspondence:

$G$ = reductive group (usually assumed to be semisimple of adjoint type) over $\mathbb{C}$, with Borel subgroup and
maximal torus $B \supset T$, Weyl group $W=N_G(T)/T$.

Fix a unipotent $u \in G$ with component group $A(u) = C_G(u)/C_G(u)^\circ$.

$\mathcal{B} = G/B$ (flag variety), containing Springer fiber $\mathcal{B}_u$
= fixed points under $u$, $d=\dim \mathcal{B}_u$ (= half codimension
of class of $u$ in unipotent variety)

Then $W \times A(u)$ acts on cohomology ($\ell$-adic or classical)
$H^*(\mathcal{B}_u)$ with top cohomology in degree $2d$.

(Springer) Each irreducible representation of $W$ occurs, for some pair
$(u,\phi)$ with $u$ unipotent and$\phi$ an irreducible character of $A(u)$, as an isotypic component of the $W \times A(u)$ representation
on the top cohomology.    Here all pairs  $(u,1)$  occur.

> Assume $A(u) \neq 1$ (possible except in type A).
>
> (1) Must some pair $(u,\phi)$ with $\phi \neq 1$ occur?
>
> (2) Is the representation of $A(u)$ on $H^*(\mathcal{B}_u)$ 
>   always a permutation permutation?

The answers to both questions seem to be yes, but I don't know
any uniform approach using Springer theory.   For example,
(1) can be checked using case-by-case study of simple
types, but is there a general reason for it?   For (2) there is 
a sophisticated indirect argument using work of Bezrukavnikov,
Mirkovic, Rumynin.     All of this ties in naturally with some
unsolved problems about representations of related Lie algebras
in characteristic $p$.

Comment: General facts about semi-small maps show that the action of $A_G(u)$ on $H^{2d}(B_u)$ is a permutation rep, but I guess what you are asking is much stronger!

Comment: Also, I thought *not* all pairs occur, but would have to hunt around a bit before justifying this comment!

Comment: Not all pairs $(u,\phi)$ occur that's true, hence the generalized Springer correspondence! The pair $(u,triv)$ however always occurs which is what I think is meant no? That follows from just from the fact that $H^{2d}(B_u)$ is a permutation rep. 

Comment: Yes, the component group permutes irreducible components of the
Springer fiber, inducing a permutation rep on top cohomology. 
(This plays a nice role for subregular unipotents.)   But the
action in lower degrees is harder to study directly.  

And yes, some pairs do fail to occur.   These are accounted for
in Lusztig's generalized Springer correspondence.   But it would
be undesirable (for me) if *all* nontrivial characters of the
component group failed to occur.   

Comment: Sorry ... I misunderstood what you are asking.

Comment: For (1): If $u$ is regular in a group with disconnected centre, then $\mathcal{B}_u$ is a point, so only $\phi=1$ appears, but $A(u)\ne1$.

Comment: @Dror: Yes, I should have specified that $G$ is semisimple of adjoint type as is usually done in the literature on Springer correspondence, to avoid such cases.    I've edited appropriately.   Thanks for pointing this out.